# php enquiry form - part filled from database

Tags: php, forms

Afternoon,

Wondering if anyone can help me. Using tables in a database I've got a form which is pre populated (from the content in the database) depending on the page the user has come in from when an enquiry is made.

Eg. if the user has come in from product A page and clicked on the 'enquiry' button from item c, the enquiry form is already pre populated with the name 'product A' and 'item c'

```
index.php?id=1&amp;pack=13
```

This is fine if the user comes in from a product page, however if the user clicks on the enquiry button at a higher level page how do I get just the product name to appear in the form? I would have thought it would have been as simple to just change the code to

```
index.php?id=1
```

However that doesn't work - the form is completing blank when doing this.

My php knowledge is very limited therefore any help is hugely appreciated.

The db table I'm wanting to target is say 'Bob', within this table I want to target the id of the individual items which selects the name of the item. This currently works as:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT Bob.Name, Bob_Packages.Name FROM Bob, Bob_Packages WHERE Bob.Id=Bob_Packages.Bob_Id AND Bob.ID = '".$id."' AND Bob_Packages.Id = '".$pack."'");
```

However I now only want 'Bob.Name' for this particular 'enquiry' link. My brain is frying!!

Many thanks,
Motley

Hi Dalionzo,
Thanks for your reply. However not really sure if it does help me out. In the current enquiry php page  I have:

```
<?php {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT Bobs.Name, Bob_Packages.Name FROM Bobs, Bob_Packages WHERE Bobs.Id=Bob_Packages.Bob_Id AND Bobs.ID = '".$id."' AND Bob_Packages.Id = '".$pack."'");
                    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                    echo $result[0];
                    }
?>
```

It's basically just the Bobs.Id I want pulling through. I gave what you supplied a try and an error was returned.

Any ideas? Thanks very much.

Comment: There's not enough information here.  What is inside index.php to start with? Where and how is the data mapping stored (id 1 to product A, pack 13 to item c, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In your query you're checking for

```
id=$id AND packages.id=$pack
```

This means, that if the query is missing one from the URL, it won't find anything at all!
So, what you have to do, is check if one of them is missing, and then create different queries using that

```
 <?php 

$query = "SELECT Bob.Name, Bob_Packages.Name FROM Bob, Bob_Packages WHERE Bob.Id=Bob_Packages.Bob_Id";

    if($_GET['id'] != '') {
    $query .= " AND Bob.ID = '".$id."'";
    }
    if($_GET['pack'] != '') {
    $query .= " AND Bob_Packages.Id = '".$pack."'";
    }

    mysql_query($query);

?>
```

Hope this helps you out!

P.S. I haven't tested this...

Comment: Please check my original post as there are both 'Bobs' and 'Bob'. While I need both 'Bobs' and 'Bob' for most enquiry links on the site, in this particular instance i only need 'Bobs.Name'